# Popular Content with statistics module incorrect

Tags: nodes

So I wrote a custom module for displaying popular nodes, that is based on the [buzzworthy](http://drupal.org/project/buzzworthy) module, but with a few tweaks. Buzzworthy has dependencies with the core statistics module.

The results are inaccurate, because when I compare with google analytics, GA yields different results. I know that GA has a latency issue, so it's like comparing apples and oranges, but another reason I know the list that my custom module displays is incorrect, is because it shows a blog post having waaaaaay more page views than it does normally.

Has anybody else had trouble with the accuracy produced by the statistics module? Is there a reason why my counts are incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons the counts from different web counters are off (I had a former boss drive me nuts with that back in 1998 ...):

- statistics module increments page counts on every reload
- when a page is cached it might not increase the statistics counter, depending on the caching used. GA does increase because it's based on browser page loads
- GA doesn't increase when bots are visiting your site (because they don't execute javascript)

I usually rely on GA for my business reports and just use statistics to show counts for my users.

You could also use the [Google Analytics](http://drupal.org/project/google_analytics) module to import GA numbers back into Drupal.